# Scan HTML for css and js links and use them in a task with Gulp

Tags: javascript, php, dom, gulp

Okay I am just throwing this out there. I have no knowlegde of PHP and little knowlegde of Javascript.

Is it possible to check an HTML file if header css/js links and body .js links exist?

**And if yes:** locate them and use them in a Gulp-task in the order they are added in the HTML file?

Example header:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Website | Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="The Most Awesome" content="Website">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/barebone.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css"> 
</head>
```

---

Use those links in a Gulptask like:

```
gulp.task('css', function(){
 gulp.src("*links in html*")
.pipe(concat('main.css'))
.pipe(prefix())
.pipe(minifyCSS())
.pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'))
.pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

I could just declare the links in the Gulp-task but I want the Gulpfile to be as generic as possible. I want to be able to just dump my files anywhere in the folder.

Comment: Sorry, typo:) ...exist

Comment: and yes, you can use [DOM](http://php.net/dom) to yank apart an html and poke around inside it.

Comment: Where should I start?

Comment: Always start at the beginning. ;)